# Fix localized wooden parquet floor scratches

Tags: hardwood-floor, parquet

I just noticed that there are some scratches on our wooden parquet floor. They are very localized and the remaining of the floor is in very good condition. Is there a way to make these invisible? They just bother the heck out of me every time I see them...

Thanks in advance!

[image: scratch example 1]
[image: scratch example 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This scratches are hardly visible so if you ask me I wouldn't do anything. But I can understand if this is bothering you; if this is the case I'm afraid that there are no hacks to fix this thing (from your question ii have realized that you are asking for a easy solution).Right way to fix it is to sand the floor and then apply lac as finishing layer. According to my knowledge this is the only way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to deal with these localized scratches...

1. You can place a rug over that part of the floor.
2. Position a piece of furniture over the scratched area.
3. You could reduce the lighting in that area and wear sunglasses inside.
4. It may be possible to sand and re-finish the whole floor if the wood is a solid wood and it has not been refinished too many times before.

Comment: +1 For the OP - the subtle (?) message here is there is no easy fix that will be less noticeable. Spot sanding and finishing is likely to be *more* noticeable  because of differences in color, gloss and transition edge to existing finish.

Comment: I tried this too. Turning off the light and using sunglasses is the best bet.  Another solution is to cover the scratches with blue painters tape, or make a bigger scratch on a wall or somewhere else that's fixable. The bigger scratch will take your attention away from the unfixable floor and make you feel accomplished after the repair.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it wouldn't make matters worse, but I'd almost be tempted to try steaming the wood to see if one could get the compressed fibers to expand back into place. Definitely test in an unnoticeable place first, but in theory... (I have a similar mark or two so I've been pondering this.)